# How to find PLSS section corners, given the ring of nodes?

Tags: united-states, centroids, canada, plss, township-range-section

1. Given a ring of nodes and centroid representing a US Public Land Survey System (PLSS, or Canada DLS) section, find the four corner nodes.
2. Do the same, but without needing the centroid.

Answer (score 0):

1. For each quadrant, the longest distance from the centroid to a node must be to (a good choice for) the corner node for that quadrant.
   [Example implementation](https://www.jidanni.org/geo/house_numbering/grids/utilities/PLSS_corners.pm).
2. We first make a bounding box, then compute which nodes are closest to each box corner. These must be (good choices for) the four corners of the PLSS section. [Example implementation](https://www.jidanni.org/geo/house_numbering/grids/utilities/PLSS_corners_4.pm).